# CLR hosting. Howto enumerate _AppDomains in .net 4

Tags: .net, clr, unmanaged, clr-hosting

I have unmanaged dll written in C, that will be injected into managed application (dotNet 4). I am going to enumerate `_AppDomains`, running in this app to load some module into domain. It is available to do this using `ICorRuntimeHost` interface. However, `ICorRuntimeHost` is deprecated, and (as described there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms164320%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) replaced with `ICLRRuntimeHost`.

How can I perform `_AppDomain` enumeration using `ICLRRuntimeHost`? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amongst the debugging interfaces there is [`ICorPublish`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231592.aspx).

You can use the [`ICorPublish::GetProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232609.aspx) method to retrieve a `ICorPublishProcess` instance for a .NET process (identified by passing the respective process ID, which can be the ID of the current process, of course).

That interface provides the method [`ICorPublishProcess::EnumAppDomains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231642.aspx), which you can use the get a list of the current application domains in the target process, via an enumerator to `ICorPublishAppDomain` instances. Each of which has the [`ICorPublishAppDomain.GetName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231461.aspx) method that gets you the name of the application domain.

*Update*: I have not tried this, but how about:

- Using the approach above to enumerate the app domains (including getting their unique ID via  [`ICorPublishAppDomain.GetID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms230288.aspx)).
- The use [`ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInAppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164410.aspx) to actually execute code in that domain (including loading the module you need to). The (first) parameter `AppDomainId` would be the value you get from `ICorPublishAppDomain.GetID()`.

There seems to be an, at least related, example (CppHostCLR) about that in the [Microsoft All-In-One Code Framework](http://1code.codeplex.com/) over on codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I'll keep on mind this interface, but it is not exactly what I need. I want to protect (encrypt) some netmodules and load it from unmanaged dll. So I need not only appdomains enumeration, but ability to load some code into specified domains.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the recommended approach: you register your own AppDomainManager with `IClrControl::SetAppDomainManagerType`, make it register with the host (with `AppDomainManagerInitializationOptions.RegisterWithHost`), receive notifications of AppDomain creation and "listen" for domain  unload through `IActionOnCLREvent::OnEvent(Event_DomainUnload)`.

That way, you already have "some code" (the domain manager) loaded into each of the domains (including the default appdomain).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Lorenzo. I even forgot what I've tried to accomplish by this, but maybe this will be usefull for someone else.

Comment: That was the goal :) I am working a lot with AppDomains lately, and when I come across an AppDomain question.. I just answer it. It may be useful for someone, in the future